# How can I make a Link to webpage like Facebook page in Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, facebook, hyperlink, dialog, clickable

I want to add my (Facebook page) link in an alert dialog like this:

```
public void visitFAcebook(){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Find Us On Facebook")
            .setMessage("www.facebook.com/mypage")

            .show();

}
```

can I convert the message to clickable link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do below changes to your code. You can change the color and font as below.

```
public void visitFacebook(){
        String fbLink = "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/mypage\">My Facebook Page</a>";
        String Txt = "Click to visit facebook: "+"<h1>"+"<font color=blue>"+ fbLink+"</font></h1>";
        Spanned fbString = Html.fromHtml(Txt);


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage(fbString);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        TextView msgTxt = (TextView) alertDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        msgTxt.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
```

Android supports only below tags

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

Comment: Thank You , very nice , but how can I control font size ,type ,alignment, and color ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please go through once. If it resolves your query, then  please mark it as an answer and upvote it so others will get correct answer.

Comment: can you please update whether above solution worked for you or not?